# Understanding Function.prototype.apply method in chain constructor

Tags: javascript

I don't know how to ask this question. i think it would be better understandable using example:([this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) example i have taken from MDN)

```
Function.prototype.construct = function (aArgs) {
  var oNew = Object.create(this.prototype);
  this.apply(oNew, aArgs);
  return oNew;
};
function MyConstructor() {
  for (var nProp = 0; nProp < arguments.length; nProp++) {
    this['property' + nProp] = arguments[nProp];
  }
}

var myArray = [4, 'Hello world!', false];
```

i can create object using two way:

1. `var obj1=new MyConstructor(4,'Hello world!', false);`
2. `var myInstance = MyConstructor.construct(myArray);`

what is the difference between creating object using these two way ? why we use apply method to create object in chain constructor and what is advantage of creating object using 2nd way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what is the difference between creating object using these two way ?

Fundamentally, the difference is whether you give the arguments as discrete arguments (#1) or as an array (#2). Also, the first way is standard, normal JavaScript; the second requires that you extend the `Function` prototype.

> why we use apply method to create object in chain constructor

So that the arguments are passed to the constructor function as though they'd been provided as discrete arguments.

This is fairly complex code, so a simpler example of what `Function#apply` does is probably useful. Let's take a boring function:

```
function foo(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
}
```

Now, let's call that with discrete arguments:

```
foo(1, 2, 3);
```

...which gives us

```
1
2
3
```

Now, let's use `apply` (ignore the `null` for now):

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
foo.apply(null, a);
```

We get the same result:

```
1
2
3
```

`Function#apply` accepts the value to use as `this` as the first argument, and the arguments for the call as an array (or array-like object) in the second argument, and calls the function with that `this` value and arguments.

> and what is advantage of creating object using 2nd way ?

Just that you can use an array for the arguments, rather than listing them individually.

Comment: according to you, object created using 2nd way extend the Function prototype. object created using first way also extend  the Function prototype.because instance of  every constructor function extend from Function.prototype. is it or i am wrong ?

Comment: @MukundKumar: *"according to you, object created using 2nd way extend the Function prototype"* No, creating the object didn't extend (add to) `Function.prototype`, your (well, MDN's) code did. What I'm saying is that you can't use #2 unless you do that bit that adds to `Function.prototype`. The resulting object will have the object that `MyConstructor.prototype` points to as its prototype, either way, because in #1 you're using `new` (which assigns it), and in #2 you're using `Object.create` to do it.